# Hadoop replication factor

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have been using hadoop for some time. When I was configuring hadoop, I came through property called dfs.replication. But I am not able to figure out how it works. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the benefits of Hadoop is that it allows you to store reliably large files in your cluster, so even if one file is corrupted you won't lose data. This works with replication: each file is divided into data blocks (which size is configurable through the property `dfs.blocksize`) which are stored in different nodes in your cluster, and each block will be replicated X times, being X the number you wrote in `dfs.replication`. Therefore, if one of your blocks of data gets corrupted, somewhere in your cluster there will be other copies of it so you won't lose data.

If you set it to 1, then it won't be fault tolerant, since it means that there is only one copy per block. However, if you set it to 2, but one block is lost, there will be another copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

Default block replication. The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created. The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
Default Value is 3, which means is u place a Dump in HDFS Location, there will be 3 replecas will be store for the same, as framework will splits the file into set of blocks( 64 MB or 128 MB) and then these blocks will be replicated across the cluster nodes.

Depends on Need and use of Data and size, the replication can be set.